# Error : multiple definition

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, header-files, multiple-definition-error

I am writing a kernel module in which i have 3 source files and one header file. When I compile it, it shows me the following error:

```
/home/karan/project/proc.o: In function `proc_read':
/home/karan/project/proc.c:23: multiple definition of `info'
/home/karan/project/main.o:/home/karan/project/main.c:23: first defined here
/home/karan/project/tx_pkt.o: In function `tx_packet':
/home/karan/project/tx_pkt.c:9: multiple definition of `info'
/home/karan/project/main.o:/home/karan/project/main.c:23: first defined here
```

I think the problem is the compiler is taking definition `struct info` more then once. But what is the solution? The `struct info` is declared in the header file . The header file is as follow:

```
int proc_write(struct file *filp,const char *buffer,unsigned long count,void *data);
int proc_read(char *buffer,char **buffer_location,off_t offset,int buffer_length,int *eof,void *data);
void tx_packet(void);

#ifndef MYDEFS_H
#define MYDEFS_H


struct inform
{
char tx_buffer[100];
struct iphdr *ip1;
};


extern struct inform info;


#endif
```

Comment: @phimuemue     I solved it actually I was writing the object of struct info there........

Comment: @torrential coding hi i solved the problem by putting extern struct info inf but now its giving me following warning:   WARNING: "info" [/home/karan/project/generate.ko] undefined!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks, you're probably right. I realized we did only move out some functions, no structs.

Comment: @karan421 Did you try the suggestion in my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use : [header guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard#Use_of_.23include_guards)

In your header do this:

```
#ifndef MYDEFS_H
#define MYDEFS_H

struct info {
    ...
    ...
};

#endif
```

Comment: @karan421 Can you edit your question to include relevant sections of code?

Comment: I have added the header file ... if you want any other code for looking .....please ask for it

Comment: @karan421 Why have you added the `extern` declaration for `info`? It's now trying to look for a definition of `info` elsewhere, hence the warning.

Answer (score -1):

I think You added the main .c file in ($(USERAPPS): $(USERSP) $(CC) -o  $@ ) here,
U include all c file except main file here